# Hide a navbar when a specific component are loaded beside the it

Tags: angular, router

I have a simple application with a different components, all componenets are configured in the router beside a navbar compoonent. Those components are called in the parent component. Like that:

```
<app-nav>

</app-nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to hide the navbar from a specific component of router-outlet.
I tried many techniques but en vain.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a state management strategy like redux or ngrx you can use the store. Otherwise, you can use a service.

Have the app component inject a service for the nav, and have the component that needs to affect the the menu inject the nav service as well. Then the component can set a flag on the service in ngOnInit or wherever necessary. The app component can subscribe to the value on the service and hide the menu as needed.

app.component.html - use async pipe to check value of observable of boolean to see if you should display the nav:

```
<app-nav *ngIf="showNav | async"></app-nav>
```

app.component - import the nav service and get the showMenu BehaviorSubject that will hold the boolean:

```
import { NavService } from 'nav.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root'
})
export class AppComponent {
  showMenu: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor(private navService: NavService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showNav = this.navService.getShowMenu();
  }
}
```

nav.service - create the BehaviorSubject that holds the nav's state in a boolean when the service is instantiated and provide methods to return the BehaviorSubject as well as set a new value to it:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class NavService {
  private showMenu: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.showMenu = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  }

  getShowMenu() {
    return this.showMenu;
  }

  setShowMenu(bool) {
    this.showMenu.next(bool);
  }
}
```

inner.component - import the navService and set the showMenu to false upon initialization of the inner component. You can call this method whenever you want to toggle the menu:

```
@Component({ selector: 'inner-component' })
export class InnerComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.navService.setShowMenu(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you detail more ?

Comment: @ToumiatFaroukNadjmeddine - I added the full boilerplate that you need for each component as well as more of a description for each piece. Let me know if that helps